# Proving Limit of Numerator Goes to 0 as Denominator Does

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I'm stuck trying to prove the (simple) fact that if $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=0$$ then $$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$$ I've started by trying for a contradiction, assuming $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = c \neq 0$ and massaging the inequalities in the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of these limits but it seems that I can't get any further. Can someone help to guide my thinking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: using the algebra of limit operation: $$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x} x = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}\lim_{x \to 0} x.$$
So in fact the original condition can be weakened to that it has any finite limit.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $0 < |x| < 1$, $\left|\frac{f(x)}{x}\right| > |f(x)|$.

Answer (score 0):

The contrapositive is that $$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)\neq o\implies \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}\neq 0$$

which is true since the limit goes to infinity.